# typeroots not has any effect in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have several questions.

**Question 1)** I have `main.ts` file , `tsconfig.json` file and then I installed `lodash` package via `npm`. Then I changed my `main.ts` file to

`import  { random }from 'lodash'` and this shows me the error about `lodash` couldn't be found.

Should I have type definitions(is it mandatory) for each package installed if I want to use them without compiler giving me errors? compiler wouldn't complain about this in the past.  What do you think?

**Question 2**) So I installed `@types/lodash` to escape the above error.  Now, I wanted to understand `typeRoots` property in compiler better. So, i added this in my `tsconfig.json's compilerOptions's object`:

`"typeRoots": [
      "./myTypes"
    ]`

now, the folder `myTypes` is empty. Why does this still work and why doens't typescript show me the error as in Question 1) because of my `typeRoots`, typescript shouldn't be able to find `types for lodash which is located in node_modules`, but still compiler doesn't give me errors at compile time. Any ideas?